# Cannot convert char to datetime in windows counters table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 that is populated with Windows perfmon data using the built in Windows processes. The table is automatically created by this process. The problem is the timestamp field is a `char` but I need a `datetime`.
I use a view on generated tables to get the data into a usable form and I want to convert the timestamp into a datetime in the view. For some reason anything I try gives me this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I can copy and paste a timestamp value from the table into a convert query and it works, like this:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '2018-04-04 00:00:08.022', 121);
```

or

```
 SELECT cast('2018-04-04 00:00:08.022' as datetime)
```

But when I try to convert a value directly from the table I get the error:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, counterDateTime, 121) from counterData
```

I have ruled out some strange format in row by selecting a specific row with a known correct format but I still get the same error.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Just to reiterate, all the values in the table are in the same format. The table was created automatically by the Windows process that writes perfmon data into the database. I have no control over the format of the data in the table. This is not specific to a row other than the one I am testing, this relates to all rows.

Example:

```
select counterDateTime from counterData where recordindex = '82331' and counterID = '1'
= 2018-04-04 00:00:08.022

select cast('2018-04-04 00:00:08.022' as datetime)
= 2018-04-04 00:00:08.023

select convert(datetime, '2018-04-04 00:00:08.022', 121)
= 2018-04-04 00:00:08.023

select cast(counterDateTime as datetime) from CounterData where recordIndex = '82331'  and counterID = '1'
= Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 109
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Here is an example tutorial for getting the Windows counter data into a database. It's a pretty standard process, there are many more examples online. The interesting tables are CounterData and CounterDetails which I aggregate with a view. It is this in the creation of this view that I would like to do the conversion.
https://logicalread.com/writing-performance-data-sql-server-mo01/#.WuxgzYgvyzU

The CounterDateTime column that I'm interested in is a nullable char of length 24.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested by following your instructions and was able to reproduce

```
SELECT ASCII(RIGHT(CounterDateTime, 1))
FROM dbo.CounterData
```

Returns 0 which is why I believe your data can't be converted. So basically 
the last character is ASCII null.

Workaround is

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(CounterDateTime, 23) AS DATETIME)
FROM dbo.CounterData
```

Comment: Thank you very much for spending the time on this, I just could not figure it out. All working as expected now and fits with my visualisation code. I find it a little strange that the Windows process would store a date as a char and cause this. I will investigate a way to communicate this to Microsoft, it should at least be noted in the documentation.